# error : virPidFileAcquirePath:422 : Failed to acquire pid file '/var/run/libvirtd

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, virtualization, libvirt

Dears,

i'm facing an issue with libvirtd process in with virtualization packages, the command "libvirtd" is always having the below error:

libvirtd
2022-11-14 15:00:53.981+0000: 315583: info : libvirt version: 3.2.0, package: 14.el7_4.7 (Red Hat, Inc. http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla, 2017-12-19-04:58:04, x86-041.build.eng.bos.redhat.com)
2022-11-14 15:00:53.981+0000: 315583: info : hostname: myhv
**2022-11-14 15:00:53.981+0000: 315583: error : virPidFileAcquirePath:422 : Failed to acquire pid file '/var/run/libvirtd.pid': Resource temporarily unavailable**

i have tried to kill the actual process and create  restart the libvirtd service, the restart was successful with a new PID for libvirtd service, the issue is that by using the command libvirtd for libvirt checks, i see the same issue.

is there anyone who has faced similar issue, or has an explanation for the same?
any help is welcoming.

Thanks in advance!